# How to delete a unaccessible volume on Mac?

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine, disk-utility, memory-management

Hi do I delete virtual partition on virtualbox?  I'm using MacOS Mojave v10.14.3 and once installed virtualbox.  I deleted the virtual machine and the app.  However, the partition is still there.  How can I remove/delete the virtual partition.  Please help as that partition is just a burden on my storage. Thanks.

Following is what when I run the command     `diskutil list` on my terminal.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         121.1 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.1 GB   disk1
                             Physical Store disk0s2
1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            36.4 GB    disk1s1
2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 45.2 MB    disk1s2
3:                APFS Volume Recovery                516.9 MB   disk1s3
4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Then when run the command: `diskutil eraseVolume APFS VM disk1s4` to erase the volume it gives the following error:

```
Started erase
Preparing to erase APFS Volume content
Checking mount state
The volume "VM" on disk1s4 couldn't be unmounted because it is in use by process 0 (kernel)
Error: -69888: Couldn't unmount disk
```

Comment: Following the steps as asked in the post, I get the following error:
    Jatins-MacBook-Air:~ jatinsinghbhati$ /usr/sbin/diskutil info / | awk '/Part of Whole/ {print $4}'
disk1
    Jatins-MacBook-Air:~ jatinsinghbhati$ /usr/sbin/diskutil apfs resizeContainer /dev/disk1 0
    Started APFS operation
    **Error: -69743: The new size must be different than the existing size**

Answer (score 1):

The volume (VM) you are trying to remove is nothing to do with VirtualBox. The volume is part of your macOS installation and would have been there prior to installing VirtualBox, and should still be there after you reinstalled macOS

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved when I erased the whole data on my mac SSD(usually named: APPLE SSD SM0128G Media - is the parent of all containers which consists the system volumes) in recovery mode and reinstalled the mac OS. Precaution: Please download the macOS in a bootable pen drive before erasing the disk to reinstall the OS afterwards. And, backup your data prior.